# How to execute existing build file in Eclipse using ant command?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I am a beginner and new to StackOverflow.

In my root folder, which has a package, I have a build file "build.xml". i wish to execute the build file using the command "ant" while in Eclipse. Example in the folder:

lklk>src>11>"Insert.java","Sort.java","build.xml"

Now, in Terminal we simply type "ant" and the project get's built into jar files.

How do I do the same in Eclipse?

PLEASE NOTE: The answer below maybe right, but the build file isn't showing up there!

Answer (score 0):

> window > show view > ant > add build.xml > hit play button

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the build.xml file.  Select: Run As > Ant Build.

Also note, you shouldn't place your build file in the src package.  I think `build.xml` should be the same level as `src`, not in it.